# Turn on vs Switch on

Tags: differences, phrasal-verbs

Which one is correct between **turn on** or **switch on** an air conditioner at home?

Comment: Which is the correct one? Wallop vs whack. Press vs depress vs click a button. An event handler vs listener. Sodium vs natrium. Violet vs purple. Obama vs GWB.

Comment: May I ask what research you have done to identify the difference or similarity?

Comment: This would have been a good question if you were able to point out what you've been able to find out so far.

Answer (score 1):

They mean the exact same thing. They're interchangeable.

Comment: Should this be answered on ELU? I doubt it would be considered of a suitable level for ELL.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth:  You know what else should be answered on ELL? Most of this week's questions here. Why zero in on this one? I proposed changes. I was mocked and sneered at. The results are before us.

Comment: @Ricky There are no exact synonyms, except (maybe) in science. If a concept has two sounds associated with it, those two sounds will have their own collocations, frequencies, whatever even if the dictionary defintions seem to coincide.

Comment: @Mitch: I was trying to keep that a secret.

Comment: @Ricky haha you're obscurantist!